# Can't login to my admin area

Tags: admin, login, redirect

I don't know what did I change, other than creating a new ftp account because the other one wasn't working with my ftp client. Now when I go to the login page, it doesn't accept my correct wp password, and this happens in the url:

http://www.ieltsonlinecourses.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://www.ieltsonlinecourses.com/wp-admin/profile.php&reauth=1

I haven't set any redirection of any kind. Please help me out, I can't login back to my own site!

Thanks,

Capex.

Answer (score 1):

If you have database access through phpmyadmin or some similar tool, you can manually set the password in the users table. The column 'user_pass' is an md5 hash of your password.

Also see this excellent resource: http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/the-agony-of-the-lost-wordpress-password/

Answer (score 1):

read this Codex Page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble and try some of that solutions.